# Have I created the mergesort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've just tried to make the mergesort algorithm. I have compared it to one I found on Geeks for Geeks, and they do not look very much alike. I wonder if I've made the mergesort algorithm correct, or if I have created a different algorithm? The two algorithms are equally efficient, so I guess some part of the algorithm is correct?

```
import random
import copy
import time

data_size = 10000
unsorted_array = random.sample(range(0, data_size), data_size)

# My version
def mergeSort(arr):
    split = []
    # Takes two and two elements from the array
    # It then puts the smallest item first in the new 
    # Returns an array consisting of smaller subarrays with two items each
    for i in range(len(arr) // 2):
        if arr[2*i] > arr[2*i+1]:
            arr[2*i], arr[2*i+1] = arr[2*i+1], arr[2*i]
        split.append([arr[2*i], arr[2*i+1]])

    # If the number of items are odd
    if len(split) != len(arr) / 2:
        split.append([arr[-1]])

    result = divide(split)
    print(result)

def divide(arr):
    i = 0
    new_arr = []
    # Merges two and two parts of the array
    while i < len(arr) // 2:
        new_arr.append(merge(arr[2*i], arr[2*i+1]))
        i += 1
    # The original array had an odd
    # number of element
    if len(new_arr) != len(arr) / 2:
        new_arr.append(arr[-1])

    # The array is not fully merged
    # The process must be repetead
    if len(new_arr) != 1:
        new_arr = divide(new_arr)

    #Return the final array
    return new_arr

def merge(left, right):
    merged = []
    total_len = len(left) + len(right)
    left_i = 0
    right_i = 0
    while len(merged) != total_len:  # Repeat until all elements of org. is merged
        if left_i < len(left):  # Check if all elements of left array has been added
            if right_i < len(right):  # Check if all elements of right array has been added
                # Add the smallest element to the merged list
                if right[right_i] > left[left_i]:
                    merged.append(left[left_i])
                    left_i += 1
                else:
                    merged.append(right[right_i])
                    right_i += 1
            else:  # Add left element, all right elements have been added
                merged.append(left[left_i])
                left_i += 1
        else:  # Add right array element, all left elements have been added
            merged.append(right[right_i])
            right_i += 1

    return merged
```

```
# From GeeksForGeeks
def mergeSort_web(arr): 
    if len(arr) > 1: 
        mid = len(arr) // 2 #Finding the mid of the array 
        L = arr[:mid] # Dividing the array elements  
        R = arr[mid:] # into 2 halves 

        mergeSort_web(L) # Sorting the first half 
        mergeSort_web(R) # Sorting the second half 

        i = j = k = 0

        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R): 
            if L[i] < R[j]: 
                arr[k] = L[i] 
                i += 1
            else: 
                arr[k] = R[j] 
                j += 1
            k += 1

        # Checking if any element was left 
        while i < len(L): 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R): 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j += 1
            k += 1

start_time = time.time()
#mergeSort(unsorted_array)
mergeSort_web(unsorted_array)
# print(unsorted_array) # Only enable for the web version 
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: do a test with multiple units? does your algorithm fail in any case?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple units"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant do a unit test with multiple test cases, then add where your code fails.

Comment: The code have not failed on any datasets I have tested, the size ranging from 8-10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written does work as a mergesort. However, it shows some differences from the web version you posted. The GeeksforGeeks version works recursively, so you will get the left half sorted first, then the right half. Whereas your code works bottom-up, putting the lists of the same size together at once. The time complexity of the two are equal and the main principle is the same.